# IllegalArgumentException in getPixels() method

Tags: android, android-bitmap, illegalargumentexception

I am setting this bitmap on canvas and getting this IllegalArgumentException while using getPixels() method:

> java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: x + width must be <=
>   bitmap.width() in the line

```
bitmap.getPixels(pixels, 0,bitmap.getWidth(), 1, 1, bitmap.getWidth(), bitmap.getHeight());
```

How to fix this?

Comment: Simple _bitmap.getWidth()_ returns _0_

Comment: The bitmap.getWidth() returns a non-zero value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the exception already tells you your error

> x + width must be <= bitmap.width()

your x and y start at 1 instead of 0, so the method calculates x + width = (1+ width) which is out of bounds.
set your x and y values to 0 or if you really want to skip the first pixel in each row and column set your bitmap.getWidth and bitmap.getHeight() to "bitmap.getWidth-1" and "bitmap.getHeight()-1".

for a better explanation see the doc

[https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Bitmap.html#getPixels(int[], int, int, int, int, int, int)](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Bitmap.html#getPixels(int[],%20int,%20int,%20int,%20int,%20int,%20int))